# SPServices UpdateListItems

Tags: spservices, updatelistitems

Ok, here's the scoop.  I have  bunch of lists on sub sites that I am rolling up into a list on the parent site.  Here is what I have for code:

```
                            var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                            $().SPServices({
                                operation: "UpdateListItems",
                                webURL: "/",
                                async: false,
                                batchCmd: "New",
                                listName: "Initiatives",
                                valuepairs: [["Title", title]],
                                completefunc: function(xData,status){
                                    alert(xData.responseText);
                                }
                            });
```

Problem is that when I execute this script, it always adds a new item, even if the name exists.  I tried switching batchCmd to "update" but then if the item doesn't exist it won't add it to the list.  Is there something built into SPServices that I could use or do I need to roll my own check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to "roll your own check". User GetListItems to see if there is an existing item and then conditionally either add a new item or update the existing one.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I just threw the titles in an array and then checked the current title to the ones loaded.  Thanks Again

Answer (score 3):

You have to roll your own, there isn't anything built in.  The closest is a form [operation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPRequireUnique&referringTitle=Documentation), SPRequireUnique.   You'd need to do a GetListItems operation to first see what's in the list, compare it to what you have and either skip it, update it, or add it.